# Faz algum sentido usar na tag area o atributo alt?

Tags: html

Pois bem, na minha perspectiva o atributo `alt` não faz o seu trabalho ao ser atribuido na tag `area` já fiz os meus teste e ele não faz o seu objetivo, que é colocar um texto alternativo quando à imagem não puder ser exibida, por exemplo, no código abaixo existe várias áreas mapeadas na imagem, [código de minha autoria](https://codepen.io/leandroDeveloper/pen/ExYpRmY?editors=1100).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>&lt;area&gt;</title>
    <style>
      img {
        width: 680px;
        height: 420px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516542076529-1ea3854896f2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ
" usemap="#mapping" alt="Imagem mapeada">
    <map name="mapping">
        <area shape="poly" coords="230, 44, 244, 140, 485, 139, 517, 44" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_de_computador" target="_blank" alt="Tela do computador">
        <area shape="poly" coords="529, 244, 575, 214, 639, 302, 593, 333" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartphone" target="_blank" alt="Telefone inteligente">
      <area shape="poly" coords="23, 248, 65, 184, 62, 179, 61, 143, 64, 142, 65, 173, 70, 180, 173, 235, 169, 240, 166, 239, 124, 304" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agenda" target="_blank" alt="Agenda">
      <area shape="poly" coords="138, 176, 147, 163, 216, 95, 222, 102, 199, 125, 197, 123, 152, 169, 141, 177" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caneta" target="_blank" alt="Caneta">
      <area shape="circle" coords="210, 319, 17" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rel%C3%B3gio" target="_blank" alt="Relógio">
      <area shape="circle" coords="541, 135, 22" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laranja" target="_blank" alt="Laranja">
    </map>

</body>
</html>
```

Caso a imagem acima não puder ser exibida ela vai amostrar o conteúdo do `alt` que é `Imagem mapeada`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>&lt;area&gt;</title>
    <style>
      img {
        width: 680px;
        height: 420px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  
    <img src="https://imadges.unsplash.com/photo-1516542076529-1ea3854896f2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ
" usemap="#mapping" alt="Imagem mapeada">
    <map name="mapping">
        <area shape="poly" coords="230, 44, 244, 140, 485, 139, 517, 44" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_de_computador" target="_blank" alt="Tela do computador">
        <area shape="poly" coords="529, 244, 575, 214, 639, 302, 593, 333" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smartphone" target="_blank" alt="Telefone inteligente">
      <area shape="poly" coords="23, 248, 65, 184, 62, 179, 61, 143, 64, 142, 65, 173, 70, 180, 173, 235, 169, 240, 166, 239, 124, 304" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agenda" target="_blank" alt="Agenda">
      <area shape="poly" coords="138, 176, 147, 163, 216, 95, 222, 102, 199, 125, 197, 123, 152, 169, 141, 177" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caneta" target="_blank" alt="Caneta">
      <area shape="circle" coords="210, 319, 17" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rel%C3%B3gio" target="_blank" alt="Relógio">
      <area shape="circle" coords="541, 135, 22" href="https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laranja" target="_blank" alt="Laranja">
    </map>

</body>
</html>
```

Só que o conteúdo do `alt` das tags `area` não são mostradas porque? na minha visão eu vejo o `alt` dentro das tags `area` como um nome para cada área dentro de um mapa de imagem que serve apenas como um nome para indentificar aquela área no meio de várias áreas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez não faça sentido pra vc pq vc enxerga com os olhos, mas para quem enxerga com um leitor de tela (screen reader), ou para um crowler de busca, como o Bot do Google, faz sentido sim essa tag, mas só se o seu `<area>` tiver o atributo `href` definido.

Veja que o atributo `alt` é sim um atributo global da tag `<area>`. No HTML4 ele era obrigatório, mesmo que vazio, já no HTML5 ele só é obrigatório se na `<area>` vc tiver definido um link com o `href`

Veja o que diz a documentação:

> In HTML4, this attribute is required, but may be the empty string (""). In HTML5, this attribute is required only if the href attribute is used.

*"No HTML4, esse atributo é obrigatório, mas pode ser a sequência vazia (""). No HTML5, esse atributo é necessário apenas se o atributo href for usado."*

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area

Resumindo o `alt` nesse caso é por uma questão semântica e de acessibilidade e não para vc ver com os olhos, o nome das áreas caso a imagem não carregue. É para ajudar os leitores de telas e bots a identificar do que se trata o link definido no `href` da `<area>`

---

**Acesso com TAB**

Repare essa simulação que eu fiz com a sua própria imagem. Repare que é possível "navegar" pelas `<area>` utilizando a tecla <kbd>tab</kbd>, tanto que quando a área é marcada ela fica com um `outline` azul. Talvez agora fique mais claro pq o `alt` é importante do ponto de vista da acessibilidade

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @leandrodonascimento vc reparou que a tag `area` não tem uma tag de fechamento tipo `</area>` isso quer dizer que ela é um elemento vazio, ou void element, então não tem como ter um texto dentro. Além do disso, quando a imagem não carrega o seu mapa fica sem coordenada, pois perde a referencia X/Y já que a imagem não renderizou na tela.

Comment: @leandrodonascimento fico feliz em ter ajudado, sucesso ai 